# Android: appearing of Screens name in Google analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics

I have just integrated Google Analytics to my APP, however I have an issue. The full activity name appears in the reports in Google analytics, such as 
**com.apps.myapp.MainActivity**  however I don't need the client to see the full name of the screen  this is my code:

1: The code in class extends application:

```
public class Google_Analytics extends Application
{
   private Tracker mTracker;

/**
 * Gets the default {@link Tracker} for this {@link Application}.
 *
 * @return tracker
 */
synchronized public Tracker getDefaultTracker()
{
    if (mTracker == null)
    {
        GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        // To enable debug logging use: adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
        mTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_trackerr);
        mTracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(true);
    }
    return mTracker;
}

}
```

2: the code in the activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

private Tracker mTracker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_city_listing_details);

    Google_Analytics application = (Google_Analytics )  getApplication();
    mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();


}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
mTracker.setScreenName("Home screen");
mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
}

}
```

3: the code in xml config

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
   <!--Replace placeholder ID with your tracking ID-->
   <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-7973XXXX-1</string>

   <!--Enable automatic activity tracking-->
  <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

  <!--Enable automatic exception tracking-->
  <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
  <screenName         
name="com.apps.myapp.MainActivity">Home Screen            
 Screen</screenName>
```

Comment: remove  
    <screenName name="com.apps.myapp.MainActivity">Home Screen            
 Screen</screenName>

Comment: i tried however it is still appears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the ga_autoActivityTracking to false:

```
<bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">false</bool>
```